# AWS Tomcat server memory is too high

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services, server

My application is running on REDHAT 6.0 on Tomcat 8. Sometimes memory usage is 100% when my application is used by 30 users at a time

**Server Configuration Details**

```
Machine ec-2 M3 Medium on AWS 
RAM : 4GB
DISK : 30GB
Processors : Intel Xeon E5-2670 v2 (Ivy Bridge) Processors
```

Is that normal? What should i do to resolve it ?

Comment: I'm surprised that you have a webapp running on a medium EC2 instance, yet you're saying that you're new to Java.

Comment: :) actually new to java means not deeply understand respect to server system

Answer (score 0):

(Didn't see the post was 3 years old)

By experiment, when the JVM is configured to use ~75% of the VM Memory (`Xmx` parameter), it will not hesitate to take as much ground as possible.

For example, our `t3.xlarge` (16GiB of RAM) instances was always at 75% of RAM Utilisation.
To investigate on that point, we used the `Java Melody` tool.
I found that the real memory utilisation of Tomcat was around 30% of the Virtual Machine max Memory even if I was triggering the GC.
The `htop` command was revealing the JVM was using 75% of the memory.

We did not updated the configuration because after many stress tests and high production pics, no issues appeared (since more than one year...).

If you want to, you can search for the Linux SIGNAL that force the JVM to release some RAM. (Linux supervise each running process by sending them signals to force them to release some resources because others need)